# how to use one collection as a parameter to function call in another collection of the same size?

Tags: c#

I have two collections known to be of the same size:

```
List<Drivers> drivers;
List<Car> cars;
```

I need to put driver from the `i` place to `i` car:

```
for (int i = 0; i < drivers.Count; i++)
    cars[i].AssignDriver(drivers[i]);
```

May I do that without loop?

Comment: You need to match driver with car? Or you want to replace entry from cars with some value from drivers? My guess is you want one-to-one relationship between driver and car.

Comment: @PawanMishra i don't understand your question, I just need to call `AssignDriver` method as I wrote in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ only for querying object, so you've to live with loop. An other way is to use [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method but I would suggest not using it since it confusing sometimes, anyway below is example in educational purposes:

```
drivers.Select((d,i) => new { Index = i, Driver = d })
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(entry => car[entry.Index].AssignDriver(entry.Driver));
```

Useful links:

- [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: It's worthy of noting that this code is less effective: it creates a new list and actually executes a double iteration (once to create the list and then to execute ForEach). Although if performance is not critical, this is fine.

Comment: Absolutely right! ToList() creates a new list instance and copy memory for each item

Answer (score 1):

Well, on the lowest level - no. You'll need to iterate anyway.

But there are some nice libraries that make handling such situations easier. For instance, there are [Interactive Extensions for .NET](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ix_Experimental-Main). Although, they are not in production state, they make it possible to do it this way:

```
cars.Zip(drivers, (car, driver) => new { car, driver })
  .ForEach(x => x.car.AssignDriver(x.driver));
```

Comment: should that be `ForEach(x => x.car.AssignDriver(x.driver));`

Comment: Is it List.ForEach() or custom extension method?

Comment: Neither. It is from the Interactive Extensions package that I referenced. It works with any IEnumerable<T> (the signature is `public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action))

Answer (score -1):

LINQ is your friend. Take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx

Note however, that I would consider your existing approach a good one too.

Comment: You should avoid modifying data (so-called side-effects) inside stateless LINQ operators like `Select`. Their semantics implies this requirement. Operators like `ForEach` in IX are designed specifically to denote that side effects are being introduced.